# Visual Studio not able to show the value of 'this' in release mode (with debug information)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

**Original question:**

Why is the this pointer 0 in a VS c++ release build?

When breaking in a Visual Studio 2008 SP1 release build with the /Zi (Compiler: Debug Information Format - Program Database) and /DEBUG (Linker: Generate Debug Info, yes) options, why are 'this'-pointers always 0x00000000?

**EDIT: Rephrased question:**

My original question was quite unclear, sorry for that. When using the Visual Studio 2008 debugger to step through a program I can see all variables, except the local object's member variables. This is probably cause the debugger derives these from the this pointer, but VS always says it's 0x00000000, so it cannot derive the current object's member variables (it does not know the memory position of the object)

When loading a megadump (Like a Windows minidump, but containing the entire memory space of the process), I can look at all my local variables (defined in the function) and entire tree-structures on the heap even I have pointers to.

For example: when breaking in A::foo() in Release mode

'this' will have value 0x00000000
'f_' will show garbage

Somehow this information needs to be available to the process. Is this a missing feature in VS2008? Any other debugger that does handle this properly?

```
class A
{
  void foo() { /*break here*/ }
  int f_;
};
```

Comment: How do you verify that the this pointer is NULL? The debugger does not always show the correct value of the this pointer in release build.

Comment: There's a workaround. When going back 1 ore more steps in the callstack, I can there find, depending on the code, the pointer of the object on which I'm calling a function.

Comment: It might also depend on what foo() does. If the optimizer decides that 'this' is no longer needed, it can reuse a register.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As some others have mentioned, compiling in Release mode makes certain optimizations (especially eliminating the use of ebp/rbp as a frame pointer) that break assumptions on which the debugger relies for figuring out your local variables. However, knowing why it happens isn't very helpful for debugging your program!

Here's a way you can work around it: at the very beginning of a method call (breaking on the first line of the function, not the opening brace), the `this` pointer will always be found in a specific register (ecx on 32-bit systems or rcx on 64-bit systems). The debugger knows that and so you should be able to see the value of `this` right at the start of your method call. You can then copy the address from the Value column and watch that specifically (as `(MyObject *)0x003f00f0` or whatever), which will allow you to see into `this` later in the method.

If that's not good enough (for example, because you only want to stop when a bug manifests itself, which is a very small percentage of the time the given method is called), you can try this slightly more advanced (and less reliable) trick. Usually, the `this` pointer is taken out of ecx/rcx very early in a function call, because that is a "caller-saves" register, meaning that its value may be clobbered and not restored by function calls your method makes (it's also needed for some instructions that can **only** use that register for their operand, like REP* and some of the shift instructions). However, if your method uses the `this` pointer a lot (including the implicit use of referring to member variables or calling virtual member functions), the compiler will probably have saved `this` in another register, a "callee-saves" register (meaning that any function that clobbers it must restore it before returning).

The practical upshot of this is that, in your watch window, you can try looking at `(MyObject *) ebp`, `(MyObject *) esi`, and so on with other registers, until you find that you're looking at a pointer that is probably the correct one (because the member variables line up with your expectation of the contents of `this` at the time of your breakpoint). On x86, the calle-saved registers are ebp, esi, edi, and ebx. On x86-64, they are rbp, rsi, rdi, rbx, r12, r13, r14, and r15. If you don't want to search all those, you could always try looking at the disassembly of your function prologue to see what ecx (or rcx) is being copied into.

Comment: you can disenable compiler optimization by the option /Od, then everything will be OK.

Comment: Nice answer, tnx! I tried casting the different registry values, but didn't find any readable information.

Answer (score 7):

Local variables (including `this`) when viewed in the Locals window cannot be relied upon in the Release build in the way that they can in Debug builds.  Whether the variable value shown is correct at any given instruction depends on how the underlying register is being used at that point.  If the code runs OK in Debug it's most unlikely that the value is actually 0.

Optimization in Release builds makes values in the Locals window a crap shoot, to the naked eye.  Without concurrent display and correlation of the Disassembly window, you cannot be sure that the Locals window is telling you the actual value of the variable.  If you step through the code (maybe in Disassembly not Source) to a line that actually uses `this`, it's more likely that you will see a valid value there.

Answer (score 6):

Because you wrote a bugged program and called a member function on a NULL pointer.

Edit: Reread your question. Most likely, it's because the optimizer did a number on your code and the debugger can't read it anymore. If you have a problem specific to Release build, then it's a hint that your code has a dodgy #ifdef in it, or you invoked UB that just happens to work in Debug mode. Else, debug with Debug build. However, that's not *terribly* helpful if you actually have a problem in Release mode you can't find.

Comment: Given the characterization (all functions affected), this is pretty unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

Your function `foo` is `inline` (it's declared in the class definition, so is implicitly `inline`), and doesn't access any members. Therefore the optimizer will likely not actually pass the `this` pointer at all when it compiles the code, so it is not available to the debugger.

In release builds, the optimizer will rearrange code quite substantially in order to improve performance, **particularly** with `inline` functions (though it does optimize other functions too, especially if whole program optimization is enabled). Rather than passing `this`, it may instead pass a pointer to a used member directly, or even just pass the member's value in a register that it loaded for a previous function call.

Sometimes the debug info is enough that the debugger can actually piece together a `this` pointer, and the values of local variables. Often, it is not, and the `this` pointer shown in the watch window (and consequently the member variables) are nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a release build. The entire point in optimizations is to change the implementation details of the program, while preserving the overall functionality.

Does the program still work? Then it doesn't *matter* that the `this` pointer is seemingly null.

In general, when you're working with a release build, you should expect that the debugger is going to get confused. Code is going to be reordered, variables removed entirely, or containing weird unexpected values.

When optimizations are enabled, no guarantees are given about any of these things. But the compiler won't *break* your program. If it worked without optimizations, it'll still work *with* optimizations. If it suddenly doesn't work, it's because you have a bug that was only exposed because the compiler optimized and modified the code.

Answer (score 1):

Are they "const" functions?

A const function is one which is declared with the keyword const, and this indicates that it will not change any of the members, only read them (like accessor functions)

An optimising compiler may not bother passing the 'this' pointer to some const functions if it doesn't even read from non-static member variables

An optimising compiler may search for functions which could be const, make them constant, and then not pass a this pointer into them, causing the debugger to be unable to find the hook.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the `this` pointer that is NULL, but rather the pointer you are using to call a member function:

```
class A
{
public:
    void f() {}
};

int main()
{
    A* a = NULL;
    a->f(); // DO'H!  NULL pointer access ...

    // FIX
    A* a = new A;
    a->f(); // Aha!
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily- as the original a is not initialized to NULL, it may contain any old garbage, and C++ does not define that there will be an exception- infact, you'll only get a Structured Exception on Windows, other platforms that are Unix-based will get a signal.

Comment: If its class A then even with NULL pointer it will be not crashed.
Check it as    ((class *)(NULL) )->f();
This will be crashed when you will access any member variable in the function f.
Anyway, non initialize locals are always having the garbage and behavior is unpredicted.

Answer (score 0):

As others already said you should make sure that the compiler does not do anything which can confuse the debugger, optimizations are likely to do.
The fact that you have `NULL` pointer can happen IF you call the function statically like :

```
A* b=NULL;
b->foo();
```

The function is not static here but called a static way.

The best spot to find the real `this` pointer is the take a look at the stack. For non-static class functions the `this` pointer MUST be the first ( hidden ) argument of your function.

```
class A
{
  void foo() { } // this is "void foo(A *this)" really
  int f_;
};
```

If your `this` prointer is null here, then you have problem before calling the function. If the pointer is correct here then you debugger is kinda messed up.

I've been using Code::Blocks with Mingw for years now, with the built in debugger ( gdb )
I only have problems with the pointer when I had optimizations turned on, otherwise it always knows the this pointer and can dreference it any time.