# Trouble With Pointers - Getting Access Violations

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, memory-management, scope

I'm having trouble understanding the ways memory is allocated with pointers.  I'm creating several "nested" structures because I need several different layers of complexity in accessing these structures...  Here's the code:

```
struct HTCoord
{
    float Position[3];

    void DebugDisplay()
    {
        std::cout << "HTCoord:" << Position[0] << ", " << Position[1] << ", " << Position[2] << " ";
    }
};

struct HTColor
{
    float Color[4];

    void DebugDisplay()
    {
        std::cout << "HTColor: " << Color[0] << ", " << Color[1] << ", " << Color[2] << ", " << Color[3] << " ";
    }
};

struct HTVertex
{
    HTCoord Position;
    HTColor Color;

    void DebugDisplay()
    {
        Position.DebugDisplay();
        Color.DebugDisplay();           
    }
};

struct HTLblVertex
{
    UINT ID;
    HTVertex *pVertex;

    void DebugDisplay()
    {
        std::cout << "ID: " << ID << " ";
        pVertex->DebugDisplay();
        std::cout << "\r\n";
    }
};

class TestCube
{
    UVFace *Faces[6];
    HTLblVertex Vertices[8];
    HTVertex VertRefs[8];


public:
    TestCube()
    {
        HTVertex TestVertices[8] = {
            { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, //0
            { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, //1
            { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, //2
            { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, //3
            { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, //4
            { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, //5
            { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, //6
            { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f }  //7
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            VertRefs[i] = TestVertices[i];
            Vertices[i] = { i, &VertRefs[i] };  //the pointer resets to null after the constructor exits            
        }


    }
    ~TestCube()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            delete Faces[i];
        }
        delete Faces;
    }

    void DebugDisplay()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "FACE " << (i + 1)<< " ";
            Faces[i]->DebugDisplay();
        }
    }
};
```

In the final class object is where the trouble seems to arise.  The variable "VertRefs" seems to stay constant and at the proper value, but the array of pointers "Vertices" no longer seems to reference it properly after leaving the constructor and calling "DebugDisplay" - they are all set to "null" or trying to read never never land.  Why are the pointers uninitializing themselves?  (obviously I'm declaring them improperly and don't understand what precisely is happening).  Any help would be appreciated - I've recently been tinkering with C++ instead of C# and it's making me irritable :-)

EDIT: I've deleted the "UVFace" code because that's not the problem I asked, but there's still this problem with the pointers and everyone got excited about UVFace code.

Comment: You left out the definition of `UVFace`.

Comment: UVFace takes a pointer which is fed by a local FaceN becoming invalid after the constructors body.

Comment: In `TestCube::~TestCube()`, you are deleting member `Faces` which is an array of pointers. It should not be deleted.

Comment: Don't just tinker with it. If you want to learn C++, get a book on it such as _Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++_ and read it. You'll never really understand C++ and it's idioms if you don't.

Comment: I have a book... I left UVFace out because it's VertRef which was the lowest stage of my problem.

Comment: Also, why swing by to just say: "I'm not going to help answer this question?"

Comment: The destructor TestCube::~TestCube() should only delete pointers or Objects and not the array. So if your pointer is an array, then you only need to delete the pointer that refers to a given memory location. For this case you only need to say: delete Faces; This will take care of the whole array.

Comment: It's an array of pointers to class objects declared with "new" in the constructor - as far as I've read, I'm supposed to delete those in the destructor.  Regardless, it's the pointers in the structure array "Vertices" which are resetting themselves to null after the "for" loop in the cube constructor.

Comment: @DieterLücking Clearly you're right about that.  I thought I had understood pointers a little better.  Why are the pointers to the elements of the "VertRefs" array becoming invalid as well even though "VertRefs" stays properly assigned?

Comment: First we are missing your class UVFace. You declared a pointer with size 6. This means your pointer can store 6 elements or Objects given the size, otherwise it would only hold one element. However if you want to declare a pointer of pointers then you do it like this: UVFace **Faces; This is a pointer that points to another pointer and still you can reallocate a size using malloc. "NEW" is not a pointer, it`s used to create an Object type. However you use a pointer to make a reference to this Object Example: UVFace *ptr = new UVFace(). To delete this is simple: delete ptr;

Comment: If you want to store pointers to Objects, then you can use vectors, this can store almost anything. However to delete these pointers in vectors, you have to traverse the entire vector size and delete all the pointers. So you will need a for loop like that one in your case.

Comment: This is how you declare a pointer of pointers. UVFace **Faces = new UVFace*[6]; so Faces is a single pointer that points to six UVFace pointers.

Comment: @Juniar I'd rather have an array that I can access by index of pointers - like I tried to make - but if those don't work for some reason, I'd love to know.  I think this would be my first time trying such a structure.  (It's actually an array of structures each of which contains a pointer).  I think I'm missing the memory allocation of something - but I can't figure out how to fix it and my book waits until like 600 pages in to even describe classes after which it has already described pointers.

Comment: @Juniar I'm not really worried about the Face Array yet as it's dependent on the "Vertices" array which is reinitializing to zero after leaving the constructor which means I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

`delete Faces` is most definitely a cause for a memory access violation.

This array is allocated statically, and should not be deallocated dynamically.

Comment: But the class object hasn't passed out of scope when I call "DebugDisplay" - why would the destructor be called while the class instance is still in scope?

Comment: You are getting an error during compile time. The compiler cannot interpret your code and so this happen at compile time and not at run time.

Comment: I'm not getting an error at compile time except for a bunch of " unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive" but they haven't seemed to prevent anything else from working and I have a whole DX11 window running.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to have been resolved.  It appear the pointers are not actually deinitizializing themselves but it's a trick of the IDE being unable to identify their value once the code block has left the object and returned.  The original memory access problem was related to creating some native arrays and passing them to "UVFace."  When the native arrays went out of scope, the "UVFace" objects were left with dangling pointers.

Since nobody had answered it, I thought I would leave this answer as once in a while I'll find stray questions in Stack Overflow that I wish had been answered from years back.

For people trying to switch languages to C++ - the essence of my problem was two fold:

**The first problem** is that a pointer does not hold an object if that object is otherwise scoped within a function unless that object is declared with "new."  The object passes out of scope and the pointer remains pointing to never never land.

**The second problem** is that Visual Studio apparently cannot necessarily discern what a member variable's pointer is pointing to if you leave a member function and come back to another member function which may falsely lead you to believe that the pointer isn't pointing to anything by examining it in the debugger.

I.E. Visual Studio was (falsely) telling me my "Vertices" array of pointers were at NULL after leaving the constructor and coming back.  This led me to believe my break in the chain was earlier than later dangling pointers.  See this question for further information on misleading debugger information if you're used to relying on the debugger to give you accurate information if you're used to C# or VB: [Visual Studio not able to show the value of 'this' in release mode (with debug information)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657188/visual-studio-not-able-to-show-the-value-of-this-in-release-mode-with-debug-i)